# Version mismatch when installing Pycbc using Anaconda (1.15.4 or 1.14.0)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have been trying to install the Pycbc package using Anaconda.

I have followed the instructions of installation on the conda-forge package page https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pycbc,

but unfortunately, the version of Pycbc installed is only 1.14.0, not 1.15.4 as the page says.

Can you help me out ? FYI I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with Python 3.7.6

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the exact command you used, as well as some more information on your environment?

Comment: This was my command  conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pycbc .